# Long waiting time when trying to reach webshop without the www. subdomain

Tags: configuration, url

When I try to reach my magento website by filling in the domain name plus top level domain in the url bar it only takes 30 seconds at least to load. 
Example: `webshopA.com`

When I try the same but with the www. subdomain then the waiting time is less than 1 second. 
Example: `www.webshopA.com`

How is this possible? What can I do speed it up?

Comment: Are both domains pointing at the server, and are they both configured correctly?  I'd expect not, however, if they are, then I would suggest adding into your virtual host configuration a redirect from one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess:
You try to reach a domain which exists but doesn't answer. So you are running in a 30second timeout, then your browser just tries with www.